# How can I pass in a function using generic types for a method to call?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, delegates

EDIT:  I just realized that what I want to do follows the Dependency Injection pattern that I learned from [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann) who wrote an [excellent book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) on the subject.  I want to have a method where I do some setup, like adding rows, but pass in an object that writes the rows to the context.  The BulkInsert method is for large "setups" and the AddRange is for smaller setups.

I have a static method where I'm passing in my DbContext, and I'm updating rows to several entities.  Depending on how I call the method, I want to either add the rows using `BulkInsert` or `AddRange`

```
public static void MySetup(MyContext, int addMethod)
{
    var list1 = new List<Foo>{......}
    if (addMethod = 1)
       context.BulkInsert(list1);
    else
       context.AddRange(list1);

    var list2 = new List<Bar>{......}
    if (addMethod = 1)
       context.BulkInsert(list2);
    else
       context.AddRange(list2);

}
```

Instead of passing in a variable, I'd like to learn how I can pass in a function instead, so it would like something like this:

```
public static void MySetup(MyContext context, ??? myAdd)
{
    var list1 = new List<Foo>{......}
    myAdd(context, list1);

    var list2 = new List<Bar>{......}
    myAdd(context, list2);
}
```

I *think* what I'm looking for is a delegate.  Note that I use different types of List classes, so whatever functions I setup on the calling end would need to accept a generic list (is that ?) because I wouldnt want to have to pass in a function for every possible type.

ETA:

BulkInsert and AddRange are both adding rows via EntityFramework.  And they each take a List.  **However** BulkInsert has an optional *options* parameter so it may be called like `context.BulkInsert(myList, opts)`

Comment: as you want to handle `Foo` **and** `Bar` a generic delegate won't do - but you can use a interface: `interface IAdd { void Add<T>(List<T> toAdd); }` and pass this around

Comment: What is the signature of `AddRange`?

Comment: @GSerg interfaces in .net are the only places where you can get a *forall types t: T<t> ...* (see here for an example I wrote about: http://gettingsharper.de/2014/09/29/church-numerals-net-and-working-around-the-value-restriction/)

Comment: AddRange is from EntityFramework, and BulkInsert is an EF extension.  They each accept a list of POCO models

Answer (score 3):

I *think* all you need is a delegate who accepts an `IList` but it is difficult to know without knowing the signature of the `AddRange` and `AddBulk` methods.

```
public static void MySetup(MyContext context, Action<MyContext, IList> myAdd)
{
    var list1 = new List<Foo> { };
    myAdd(context, list1);

    var list2 = new List<Bar> { };
    myAdd(context, list2);
}
...

Action<MyContext, IList> insertRange = (context, list) =>
{
    context.AddRange(list);
};

Action<MyContext, IList> insertBulk = (context, list) =>
{
    context.BulkInsert(list);
};

MySetup(new MyContext(), insertRange);
// or...
MySetup(new MyContext(), insertBulk);
```

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this answer please tell me what is wrong? Ta.

Comment: I mean _no offense_ whatsoever to the OP _but_ when I read "I think what I'm looking for is a delegate" and see `???` in place of a delegate type, I _assumed_ this question to be written by who is struggling with basic delegates in which case, there _is_ a question to begin with.

Comment: The only problem is that I need to have the action blurb  determine what table in the context to use.  eg.   context.XXX.AddRange(list);  where XXX is the <T> of list.

Comment: I think an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is starting to emerge. I really want to help you but at the moment what you want to do is unclear. I think you are going down the wrong path with delegates, basically. If you updated your question to show what you actually want to do then I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Quite possible this is a YAGNI situation and I should stick with a simple if statement, however I'm a curious monkey and just want to know for the sake of it.   Your solution is exactly what I was looking for -- except for `context.AddRange`.  You must specify an entity of the context when using AddRange.   eg `context.Projects.AddRange(list)`. Oddly,  you don't have to specify the entity for the bulkinsert extension.   It's just context.bulkinsert(list)

Answer (score 1):

I thought long about if I should post it (as it does kind of answer the question but I don't think it solves the problem behind) but so be it:

If you know all the possible types you are going to use up front the easiest way would be this:

```
interface IAddStuff 
{
    void Add (MyContext context, IList<Foo> list);
    void Add (MyContext context, IList<Bar> list);
}

class Operations
{
    public static void MySetUp(MyContext context, IAddStuff adder)
    {
        var list1 = new List<Foo> ();
        adder.Add (context, list1);

        var list2 = new List<Bar> ();
        adder.Add (context, list2);
    }
}

class SampleImplementation : IAddStuff 
{
    public void Add(MyContext context, IList<Foo> list)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Add(MyContext context, IList<Bar> list)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Now if you don't know exactly you can still do runtime-dispatch (and let the implementation decide):

```
class MyContext {}
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

interface IAddStuff 
{
    void Add<T> (MyContext context, IList<T> list);
}

class Operations
{
    public static void MySetUp(MyContext context, IAddStuff adder)
    {
        var list1 = new List<Foo> ();
        adder.Add (context, list1);

        var list2 = new List<Bar> ();
        adder.Add (context, list2);
    }
}

class SampleImplementation : IAddStuff 
{
    public void Add<T> (MyContext context, IList<T> list)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Foo)) 
            AddFoo(context, list.Cast<Foo>());
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Bar)) 
            AddBar(context, list.Cast<Bar>());
    }

    void AddFoo(MyContext context, IEnumerable<Foo> list)
    {
        // ...
    }

    void AddBar(MyContext context, IEnumerable<Bar> list)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now as you can see you only moved the **problem** (the runtime check for what kind of generic type you really have) into the implementation of said interface *but* you can keep your other code a bit more clean.

Don't know if you find this useful but this is the nearest **I** can come to what I think *you asked*.

**PS** it should be obvious of how you can update this with some parameter to tell if it should use *bulk-insert* or not.

**PPS** and yeah you can *misuse* the `dynamic` stuff to get the dynamic-dispatch without the `if`s ... but I don't like those very much - if you are interested in it anyway here is [an example where this *trick* is used](https://github.com/jfellien/SeekYouRS/blob/version-1.6/SeekYouRS%20CQRS%20Framework/Sample.CQRS.Domain/CommandHandler/CustomerCommands.cs)

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for.  The only negative is I have to create classes for each model (Foo, Bar) etc.  If I add/delete new models, then I have to update this class as well.  I guess that's what tests are for.

Answer (score 0):

If Foo and Bar share a common interface, then you can pass the method in using the [Action delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx).

**For example:**

```
public interface IBaz
{
}

public class Foo : IBaz
{     
}

public class Bar : IBaz
{
}

public static void MySetup(DurianContext context, Action<DurianContext, List<IBaz>> addMethod)
{            
    List<IBaz> list1 = new List<IBaz>();
    addMethod(context, list1);

    List<IBaz> list2 = new List<IBaz>();
    addMethod(context, list2);
}
```